# Amsterdam 2 day pass validity

Tags: tickets, public-transport, amsterdam

I'm considering buying a 2 day pass for Amsterdam (https://www.discoverholland.com/amsterdam-travel-ticket). I was wondering how to figure out what routes are included and which ones are not. It seems to be tied to the operator, but I have no idea who operates which line.

Specifically the ticket seems to include bus 397 from the city to the airport, but does the ticket also cover stations on that line past the airport? I have to go to Nieuw Vennep. If the card doesn't cover it, how can I pay for the additional stations?

Comment: If you have a (credit or debit) card that works on touching or a phone or watch with which you can pay you can pay in the bus. I doubt the Amsterdam card will work beyond the airport, as it is an Amsterdam based product, but as fairly local I have never used it.

Answer (score 6):

[Bus 397](https://www.connexxion.nl/en/our-routes/special-routes/amsterdam-airport-express) is operated by Connexxion (but to make things more confusing, the buses have the red “R-Net” livery that is shared between several operators and not the white/green livery of regular Connexxion buses).

The description of the [Amsterdam Travel Ticket](https://gvb.nl/en/travel-products/tourists/amsterdam-travel-ticket) on the GVB website seems a little more specific:

> The Amsterdam Travel Ticket provides unlimited travel on the train (NS railway), the Amsterdam Airport Express (bus 397) and Niteliner N97 (of Connexxion) between Schiphol and Amsterdam and unlimited travel for all GVB trams, day buses, night buses and metros.

Hard to say for sure but seems to confirm that only travel between the airport and Amsterdam is included. Unlimited travel on other routes is only for GVB buses.

To pay for additional stations, you can just tap a pay-as-you-go transit card, a debit card or a credit card when you reach the end of the coverage area, as you would do when getting on the bus at that station. In buses and trams, [you will find card readers at every door](https://www.connexxion.nl/en/tickets/ovpay-checking-in-and-out-with-your-debit-card) and every card reader can be used to tap in or out (i.e. even if the door is marked as an exit door, you can still tap in) so you don't need to walk off the bus or go all the way to the front. Do not forget to tap out when exiting the bus!

You will however be charged for the full price of a trip from, say, Schiphol to Nieuw Vennep, including a fixed €1.08 boarding fee (*basistarief*) and not merely some “top-up fare” that would only be valid together with your day card.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be able to reach Nieuw Vennep and want to have a 2-day ticket you could also look at the [Amsterdam region travel ticket](https://www.connexxion.nl/en/shop/tickets/amsterdam-region-travel-ticket)

It's 31.50 euro for 2 days and is valid for:

> All metro, tram and bus lines operated by GVB, Connexxion, AllGo and EBS, including night buses in the Amsterdam Area. Tickets are also valid on NS trains in the Amsterdam Area.

The Dutch version of the ticket page has [a helpful PDF map](https://www.connexxion.nl/getmedia/13320acf-9c81-4d4e-9595-330ecb8fc831/artt-map.pdf) that shows exactly which lines are covered (curiously the map is missing from the English page...). In the lower left you can see that bus 397 is covered all the way until Nieuw-Vennep:

[image]

Note that the train is *not* covered until Nieuw-Vennep by this ticket (grey railway line).

An alternative if you will only be travelling a few times is to [buy separate e-tickets for your journeys through the 9292 app](https://9292.nl/en/fares-and-public-transport/purchase-your-ticket-in-the-app). It does require a bit more hassle as you have to buy each public transport ticket separately, but depending on your situation it can be cheaper.